# How to include a reference column with the OUTPUT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, output-clause

I have a reference **TableA** with a single column called [**SomeID**]:

| SomeID |
| --- |
| ABC |
| DEF |
| GHI |
| KLM |

I have **TableB** can be:

```
CREATE TABLE TableB([ID] BIGINT, [Name] NVARCHAR(50))
```

[ID] is the primary key and is auto-increment.

I want to create a new record in **TableB** for each record of **TableA**.

So we do this:

```
DECLARE @OuputTable TABLE([ID] BIGINT, [SomeID] NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO TableB([Name])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID], 'Need Associated SomeID From TableA Here' INTO @OutputTable
SELECT 'ZZZZZZ' -- Edited this line to remove some possible confusion.
FROM TableA

SELECT *
FROM
@OuputTable
```

How would I be able to place the associated [**SomeID**] value for each of the created record in **@OuputTable** without using a loop?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Using SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `MERGE INTO` which might allow you get source data value in `OUTPUT`

```
MERGE INTO TableB AS dest
USING TableA AS sou ON 1=0   
WHEN NOT MATCHED       
    THEN INSERT ([Name])
         VALUES (sou.[SomeID])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID], sou.SomeID
INTO @OutputTable (ID, SomeID);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=2621cf96dbb807190992efc3d4817135)

Comment: I did some tests and that seemed to have worked.  Thank you.